# How to know EC2 instance stopped time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I really need to know about the stopped time of AWS EC2 instances. I have checked with AWS cloudtrail, but its not easy to find the exact stopped EC2 instance. Is possible to see exact time of stopped EC2 instances by aws-cli commands or any boto3 script?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this info from `StateTransitionReason` in [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) AWS CLI when you search for stopped instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped --query 'Reservations[].Instances[*].StateTransitionReason' --output text
```

Example output:

```
User initiated (2020-12-03 07:16:35 GMT)
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, Many thanks for your reply. I have tried this aws-cli commands before some time. But i got answer like this.                                                
 User initiated (2020-12-02 16:51:25 GMT)
User initiated
I can't able to see some of instances stopped time. But its stopped from one of webportal which is developed for our future.

Comment: Why that particular instance doesn't shown time of stopped.

Comment: @Latchu Don't know. Maybe its only showed for user imitated actions.

Comment: Okay brother. Is possible to see stopped of all EC2 instances by using any services or anything?

Comment: @Latchu  CloudTrial possibly.

Comment: Yes, I have preferred cloudtrail very first. But i cant able to find the status of EC2 instances very easily. Is there any way to look about particular EC2 instances in CloudTrail?

Answer (score 1):

**AWS Config** keeps track of the state of resources as they change over time.

From [What Is AWS Config? - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html):

> AWS Config provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.

Thus, you could look back through the configuration history of the Amazon EC2 instance and extract times for when the instance changed to a `Stopped` state.

Comment: Just now i enabled the AWS config for EC2 instances, I will check and update here. Many thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes time is missing from `StateTransitionReason`, you can use CloudTrail and search for Resource Name = instance ID to find out `StopInstance(s)` API calls.

By default you can track back 90 days, or indefinitely if you create your own trail.

Answer (score -1):

As explained in other answers, `StateTransitionReason` from [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_instances.html) will give state transition time but this is only for User Initiated shutdowns.

If it is OS initiated shutdown, `State transition reason` will be `Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown` and in this case, we can't find the stopped time.